# Having issues accessing a method

Tags: java

just a quick question in relation to accessing a method inside another class. 
I know it sounds simple but nowhere I look can answer it for me.. so here it goes.

This is in one class.. (only leaving in the relevant bits because most of the other stuff is just formatting and passing around values.)

```
public class ContactManager extends JFrame{ 
   public void getData()throws FileNotFoundException{
   ...
   ...
       private class thehandler  implements ActionListener {
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getSource() == viewButton && selectedIndex != -1){
                       ViewContact view = new ViewContact();
                       view.pack();
               view.setVisible(true);




public class ViewContact extends JFrame { 
            ... 
            ...
                private class viewhandler implements ActionListener {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                            if (event.getSource() == updateButton){                         
                                      getData(); //this method i want to use thats in the contact manager window is what im having issues with.
                 }
```

I know the syntax is wrong for accessing a method in another class I just wanted to show what i am trying to do. I cannot create another instance of the contact manager class because I am already using it.. :S at least i think that's the issue. 
I hope I have left in enough relevant information and thank you in advance for assistance with this.

Comment: Why you cannot create you can create instance of ContactManager as answers below.

Comment: because ContactManager had been already initialized and i wanted to update that instance from another class.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to your question is that you can pass an appropriate instance of `ContactManager` to the `ViewManager` and call `getData()` as required:

```
class ViewManager extends JFrame {
    private ContactManager cm;

    public ViewManager(ContactManager cm) {
        this.cm = cm;
    }

    private class Handler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            cm.getData();
        }
    }
}
```

The longer answer is that it might be better to separate your business logic from your view logic and put the `getData` method into a business-layer class:

```
class DataSource {
    public Data getData();
}

class ContactManager extends JFrame {
    private DataSource dataSource;
    public ContactManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        ...
    }
}

class ViewContact extends JFrame {
    private DataSource dataSource;
    public ViewContact(DataSource dataSource) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This decouples the classes that are responsible for fetching/managing data from the classes that are responsible for displaying it. It means you can change the view without affecting the way data is stored, or you can change the way data is stored without affecting the view.

Comment: Thank you, this will work perfectly! I especially liked your longer answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a constructor for ViewContact() that accepts a reference to your ContactManager instance?  For example:

```
  ViewContact myContact = ViewContact (this);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call data()!

You can create another class-instance of ContactManager too.

You can also create instances of ViewContact using:

```
ContactManager m = new ContactManager();
JFrame contact = m.new ViewContact();
```

You even can instance thehandler using this:

```
    ContactManager manager = new ContactManager();
    Object b = null;
    for (Class<?> clazz : ContactManager.class.getDeclaredClasses()) {
        if (clazz.getSimpleName().equals("thehandler")){

            for (Constructor<?> constructor : clazz.getDeclaredConstructors()) {
                constructor.setAccessible(true);
                b=constructor.newInstance(manager);
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No. `m.new ViewContact()` is not valid Java syntax.

Comment: Using reflection to achieve this kind of thing is going to be slow, bug-prone, very difficult to understand and unlikely to work if there is a `SecurityManager`. Calling methods like `setAccessible` is generally a Very Bad Idea because it violates access control and is likely to cause your code to behave unexpectedly. Apart from anything else, you are attempting to call `newInstance` on *each* declared constructor which will throw an exception for all except the no-arg. I didn't downvote before because you're clearly not an experienced programmer, but this idea is just terrible. -1.

Comment: @CameronSkinner A few years are gone, are you more experienced in java now and can confirm that it is valid java syntax?